# get custom image size

Tags: posts, images

In a post I want to place a custom image. how do i place a thumbnail with link to original image? below is my current code.

```
<a href="[site_url]/wp-content/uploads/GABON-Leopard-Gas-Discovery-1x1.jpg"><img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-5435" src="[site_url]/wp-content/uploads/GABON-Leopard-Gas-Discovery-1x1-200x112.jpg" alt="GABON-Leopard-Gas-Discovery-1x1" width="288" height="288" /></a>
```

I had to manually put in `-200x112` . is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: You can select image/thumbnail size from `Attachment Display Settings` (right column) in media upload popup.

Comment: im not using visual editor, as it messes up layout of post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the image's ID :

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, array(200, 112) );
```

returns an HTML img element or empty string on failure.  The entire code could be something like :

```
<a href="<?= get_attachment_link( '5435' ); ?>">
   <?= wp_get_attachment_image( '5435', array(200, 112) ); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using wp_get_attachment_image_src() function get the original url of thumbnail

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
$image = $image_url[0];
```

}

Then add Image Url to your custom code

```
<a href="<?php echo $image; ?>"><img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-5435" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="GABON-Leopard-Gas-Discovery-1x1" width="288" height="288" /></a>
```

I think it will work fine